# how to merge pdf as a table with pdftk or convert

Tags: linux, pdf, pdftk

How can one use `convert` or `pdftk` to merge several pdfs organized as a table?
For example, given 4 files: file1.pdf, file2.pdf, file3.pdf, file4.pdf, each of a single page, I would like to have a single-page pdf like

```
file1.pdf     file2.pdf

file3.pdf     file4.pdf
```

That is, the files are arranged like an array.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfnup

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way to convert 4 PDF pages to 1 page on any OS is by N-Up imposition/printing with output to a virtual PDF printer such as Ghostscript. For the most basic 4-Up command line usage see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72850245/10802527

Thus to combine 4 pages (others such as 2 6 9 or 16 are possible) using here in a gui I can very easily set the order.

[image]

On Linux or MacOS you can use, along with other options, the CUPS command

```
lp -o number-up=4 filename
```

see https://www.cups.org/doc/options.html

The major advantage over using tools such as PDFtk with convert is that it resolves both scaling and preserving most PDF structures without degrading to inferior down-scaled imagery by NOT passing in and out of images before calling Ghostscript.

If you have single pdfs then you can merge before print using PDFtk (uses Ghostscript) instead of poppler pdfunite. Note that with either the Original PDF format is preserved.

If you want to convert to half size images and stitch them together, then reprint to one pdf page, then that can easily be done using imagemagik convert and other commands to call Ghostscript to suit your requirements direct. However, the results will in many ways be degraded by translation to image output.

Since all of the above pass through GS it makes sense, where possible, to install GS as a PDF printer driver.

If you want to avoid installing GhostScript printing then you can use cross platform Coherent cpdf (it only uses GS if the files need repairs)

Note these are "windows double quoted names" adjust as required and is based on the 4 sequential pages in one file are then to be placed 4 at a time on each new page, thus can be used with any multiple of pages in the input.pdf

```
cpdf -twoup "input.pdf" -o "in-2-Up-tmp.pdf"
cpdf "in-2-Up-tmp.pdf" -rotate 90 -o "out-2-Up.pdf"
cpdf -twoup "out-2-Up.pdf" -o "out-4-Up-tmp.pdf"
cpdf "out-4-Up-tmp.pdf" -rotate 90 -o "out-4-Up.pdf"
```