# php merge one file pdf size a6 into a4 size

Tags: php

i have one pdf file size A6. In that file have multiple page. i want merge/convert/combine that file into A4 paper size pdf.

Example on A6 size pdf (one file only) have **7** pages. Then i want convert to A4 size let it became one file have 2 page. On A4 size, page 1 will have **4** A6 page then page 2 will have **3** A6 page.

Which composer i should use to process this all method? if not required composer its much more better. Also anyone have example code about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ghostscript is the all platform GoTo application for command line PDF processing.

Recent versions 9.54+ have improved N-Up imposition, you will need to experiment with settings. If you require more complex control say for booklet production with folds that require inversion, you may need to consider other command methods involving rotations:- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494232

[image]

However you are only attempting simple 4-up on a page, Again there are many methods using command lines but in this simplest case you can use a simple command.

```
gs -dNEWPDF -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o 4perPage.pdf -sNupControl=2x2 -sDEFAULTPAPERSIZE=a4 -dFitPage -f in.pdf
```

The order will be across then second row with blank for any shortage. thus its Z-Up rather than mirrored Ͷ-Up.

[image]

Comment: can ghostscript use php command? also i need own server to install this right?